# OnDisconnected not called when published to IIS server works fine in Visual Studio

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, signalr, asp.net-web-api, signalr-hub

Please forgive me if this has already been asked before. I looked around, but my situation didn't come into play on any answered question I came across.

I'm Using SignalR 2.2.0
Setup: I have a WebAPI 2 web application (call it API For short) that holds my hub called ChatHub. I have a MVC site (MVC) that is calling my hub on the API site.

Both of these sites are on the same server just different ports. I am using VS 2013 and when I test locally, my local system also uses the same ports...also the url to the API site is loaded from the web config which is different for Release and Debug and local(so the url is correct and the ports on the server are fine...really on thing wrong is OnDisconnectednot getting fired)

After a lot of trial and error and searching, I finally got a test application up. Everything was working perfect. Then I had to modify my hub fit into the business model. IE Take the in memory list of users and messages and record them in the database (among other things). Everything work perfectly when running locally, however once the sites are published to IIS on the server....The OnDisconnected is never called. On the test app / when running locally, this is almost instantly hit by most browsers. But even after waiting 15+ minutes, the method is still not fired.

Here is my hub:(shorted for clarity)

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Chat Hub Class
   /// </summary>
   public class ChatHubAsync : Hub
   {
      #region Data Members
      IDemographicsProvider DemographicsProvider { get; set;}
      IChatRepository Repo { get; set; }
      #endregion

      #region CTOR 
      /// <summary>
      /// Unity Constructor
      /// </summary>
      [InjectionConstructor]
      public ChatHubAsync()
         : this(new ChatRepositoryEF(), DataProviders.Demographics)
      {        
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// Constructor for Chat Hub
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="Repository"></param>
      /// <param name="Demographics"></param>
      public ChatHubAsync(IChatRepository Repository, IDemographicsProvider Demographics)
      {
         Repo = Repository;
         DemographicsProvider = Demographics;
      }
      #endregion

      #region Methods
      /// <summary>
      /// On Connected method to call base class
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public override async Task OnConnected()
      {
         await base.OnConnected();
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// Connect to Hub
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns>Void</returns>
      public async Task Connect()
      {
         if (await Repo.GetUser(Context.ConnectionId) == null)
         {
            await RemoveDuplicates(getGuidFromQueryString("userID"), getGuidFromQueryString("groupID"));
            var user = await CreateUser();
            await Repo.Connect(user);
            await Clients.Caller.onConnected(user);
         }
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// Add User To Group
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public async Task AddToGroup()
      {
         Guid id = getGroupFromQueryString();
         if (id != Guid.Empty)
         {
            string groupID = id.ToString();
            var user = await Repo.GetUser(Context.ConnectionId);
            try
            {
               if(user == null)
               {
                  await Connect();
                  user = await Repo.GetUser(Context.ConnectionId);
               }
               await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupID);
               var users = await Repo.OnlineUsers(id);
               var messages = await Repo.RetrieveMessages(id, 20);
               var status = await Repo.AddOnlineUserToGroup(Context.ConnectionId, id);
               await Clients.Caller.onGroupJoined(user, users, messages, status);
               Clients.Group(groupID, Context.ConnectionId).onNewUserConnected(user);
            }
            catch(Exception E)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(E.Message);
            }
         }
      }

    /// .....More Methods that are irrelevant....

      /// <summary>
      /// Disconnect from Hub
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="stopCalled"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
      {
         try
         {
            var item = await Repo.GetUser(Context.ConnectionId);
            if (item != null)
            {
               if (item.GroupID != null && item.GroupID != Guid.Empty)
               {
                  var id = item.GroupID.ToString();
                  Repo.Disconnect(Context.ConnectionId);
                  Clients.OthersInGroup(id).onUserDisconnected(Context.ConnectionId, item.UserName);
                  Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, id);
               }
            }
         }
         catch (Exception E)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(E.Message);
         }
         await base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
      }
      #endregion

      #region private Messages

      private async Task<IOnlineUser> CreateUser()
      {
        ///Code removed
      }   

      private Guid getGroupFromQueryString()
      {
         return getGuidFromQueryString("groupID");
      }
      private Guid getGuidFromQueryString(string name)
      {
         Guid id;
         try
         {
            var item = getItemFromQueryString(name);
            if (Guid.TryParse(item, out id))
            {
               return id;
            }
            throw new Exception("Not a Valid Guid");

         }
         catch(Exception E)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(E.Message);
            return Guid.Empty;
         }
      }
      private async Task RemoveDuplicates(Guid User, Guid Group)
      {
         ///Code removed
      }
      #endregion
   }
```

UPDATE:

I have no idea why, but once I removed the calls to the database (ALL CALLS TO THE DATABASE) and went back to in memory lists, On Disconnected started getting called again.

Added back any call to the database using either straight sql or EntityFramework and the OnDisconnected stopped getting called.

Any ideas why adding database calls would cause the onDisconnected to stop getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is having this issue. The problem was caused by the application not impersonating the correct user....it worked fine in visual studio because when impersonation failed to use the provided user, it used me. Out side of VS it didn't have that option and tried using the machine account which failed to log in. This was fixed by adding the impersonation in the application pool instead of using it in the web config. I was having issues with this earlier in the project when using async calls, but I thought I had those fixed with a few changes to the web config. I worked for all the async calls that I was making, but it was still failing in a few select areas that was causing the OnDisconnect to not fire on the server.